# Using spring @Cachable annotation , i want to pass cache region(value={}) using spring el

Tags: spring, ehcache

I want to assign `cache` name using `spring el` but i am getting below exception.
is there any way to pass `cache` name using `spring el`.

```
@Cacheable(value={"#p0"} ,key="#url", condition="#doCache")
    public byte[] httpGetAsByteArray(String cacheRegion,String url,HttpHeaders headers, List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes, boolean doCache,boolean proxyRequest) throws HttpBeanException, AuthenticationFailedException {

//logic is here.
}
```

Getting exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named '#p0' for Builder[public byte[] com.vodafone.global.vfstart.juno.http.integration.service.HttpIntegrationService.httpGetAsByteArray(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,java.util.List,boolean,boolean) throws ] caches=[#p0] | key='#url' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='#doCache' | unless='' | sync='false'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception message and the [`@Cacheable` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html), it seems Spring EL is not supported on the `value` or equivalent `cacheNames` attribute.

You may be able to achieve what you want by leveraging the [`cacheResolver` attribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver).